# Efficient algorithm for taking powers of binary numbers?

Tags: algorithms, binary

Is there any efficient algorithm for taking powers of binary numbers? Or even just squaring one?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reference that I found:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method

The most intuitive algorithm that I can think of for squaring binary numbers involves appending zeros and adding. As an example, say you want to square $101101$. To do so, note the position of each $1$ in the number (this can be done algorithmically by right-shifting and doing an AND with $1$. In our example, we have $1$'s in the 1st, 3rd, 4th, and 6th positions. So we would add

$$ 101101 + 10110100 + 101101000 + 10110100000$$

where for each addend you append the position of the corresponding $1$ minus one. Since you have $1$'s in the 1st, 3rd, 4th, and 6th positions you would append $ 1- 1 = 0$, $3 - 1 = 2$, $4 - 1 = 3$, and $6 - 1 = 5$ zeros to each of the four addends respectively.

Comment: Nice and clear explanation, but the algorithm is simply [peasant or binary multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Peasant_or_binary_multiplication), isn't it? It doesn't actually exploit the fact that multiplier and multiplicand are the same number. Maybe this algorithm would be faster in some cases (but also harder to implement): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377430/why-is-squaring-a-number-faster-than-multiplying-two-random-numbers/16388571#16388571

Answer (score 2):

Reducing exponentiation to squaring and occasional multiplication
seems to be fast, see [Exponentiation by Squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).
It uses
$$
x^n =
\begin{cases}
x \, ( x^{2})^{(n - 1)/2}, & \mbox{if } n \mbox{ is odd} \\
(x^{2})^{n/2} , & \mbox{if } n \mbox{ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
The squaring is done by $x^2 = x * x$.

In Henry S. Warren's "Hacker's Delight", chapter 11-3, a method called
„Computing $x^n$ by Binary Decomposition of $n$“ is presented, but it seems to be the same idea at first glance (please check this).
$$
x^{13} = x^{(1101)_2} = x^{8+4+1} 
= x^8*x^4*x
= \underbrace{(\underbrace{(\underbrace{(\underbrace{1^2 * x}_1)^2}_0 * x}_1)^2)^2 * x}_1 
$$
One starts with initial value $1$ and the exponent representation is read right to left and either a "square and multiply" (if $1$) or "square" step (if $0$) is taken, see example above.

The other idea that comes to mind, but depends on how large your numbers are, in this case rather be small, is using some kind of [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

Answer (score 0):

And if you want
to square 
(or multiply)
very large numbers,
there is the
Karatsuba algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm